# Get the first start time and last end time

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I have an initial query result in the first images.

```
select 
    rpt_mem.Member_Full_Name as Member,
    rpt_mem.Email_Address as [Work Email],
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Date_Time_Start, 101) as [Shift Start Date],
    MIN(CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), Date_Time_Start, 108)) as [Shift Start Time],
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Date_Time_End, 101) as [Shift End Date],
    MAX(CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), Date_Time_End, 108)) as [Shift End Time]
from Schedule
where rpt_mem.Member_Full_Name = 'Member1'
AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Date_Time_Start, 101) = '10/04/2020'
```

[image: Query result]

How can I modify the query to get only the first Shift Start Time and the last end time like the 2nd image

[image: target result]

Comment: Data is best displayed as formatted text on this site. Images are a pain for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `group by` only the date portion of `Date_Time_Start` and `Date_Time_End`.

```
declare @Schedule table (Member varchar(8), Date_Time_Start datetime2(0), Date_Time_End datetime2(0))

insert into @Schedule (Member, Date_Time_Start, Date_Time_End)
values
('Member 1', '10 Apr 2020 12:00:00', '10 Apr 2020 14:00')
, ('Member 1', '10 Apr 2020 17:00:00', '10 Apr 2020 18:00')

select 
    , CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), convert(date,S.Date_Time_Start), 101) as [Shift Start Date]
    , CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), MIN(S.Date_Time_Start), 108) as [Shift Start Time]
    , CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), convert(date,S.Date_Time_Start), 101) as [Shift End Date]
    , CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), MAX(S.Date_Time_End), 108) as [Shift End Time]
from @Schedule S
where S.Member in ('Member 1')
--AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Date_Time_Start, 101) = '10/04/2020'
-- Sargeable i.e. can make use of indexes.
AND S.Date_Time_Start >= '10 Apr 2020'
AND S.Date_Time_Start < '11 Apr 2020'
group by S.Member, convert(date,S.Date_Time_Start), convert(date,S.Date_Time_End);
```

Which returns:

```
Member      Shift Start Date    Shift Start Time    Shift End Date  Shift End Time
Member 1    04/10/2020          12:00               04/10/2020      18:00
```

Notes:

1. You don't want to be converting your `Date_Time_Start` in your `where` clause because its non-sargeable. Instead use a window condition.
2. You want to get in the habit of using a non-ambiguous date format.
3. This query will allow you to run over multiple days and multiple members should you wish to. You'd just have to add any addition member information columns e.g. Email to the `group by`.
4. If you setup test data using DDL/DML statements as shown you make it easier for people to answer your question.

Comment: Thank you @Dale K for pointing out some items. Will try this and review.

Answer (score 0):

You may also do -

```
select 
    rpt_mem.Member_Full_Name as Member,
    rpt_mem.Email_Address as [Work Email],
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), MIN(Date_Time_Start), 101) as [Shift Start Date],
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), MIN(Date_Time_Start), 108) as [Shift Start Time],
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), MAX(Date_Time_End), 101) as [Shift End Date],
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), MAX(Date_Time_End), 108) as [Shift End Time]
from Schedule rpt_mem
where rpt_mem.Member_Full_Name = 'Member1'
AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Date_Time_Start, 101) = '04/10/2020'
GROUP BY 
 rpt_mem.Member_Full_Name,
 rpt_mem.Email_Address;
```

Here is a db fiddle link - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=61da8cab5471d21818eb5b7fec8d509c